# Google DataStudio SSL connection to MariaDB

Tags: ssl, mariadb, connection, looker-studio

I try to connect Google Data Studio to my MariaDB's server without success.
It works fine if I use the MySQL connector of Google Data Studio without SSL.

I setup the SSL server certificates and clients certificates also (ca-cert, server-cert, server-key, client-cert, client-key).
I setup the server.cnf to use the server's certificates.
I did a test to connect the database with SSL from an external Linux machine using the client's certificates and it works fine.

I provide the ca-cert, client-cert and client-key to Google Data Studio connector, but I have an errors:

> impossible to connect

If I check the server MySQL error log the only error I have is:

> Aborted connection xx to db: 'mydb' user: 'myuser' host: 'x.x.x.x' (CLOSE_CONNECTION)

Is there something particular to do for Google Data Studio SSL connection?

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB version 10.1.x will not work with Google Data Studio as it is compiled with yaSSL that only supports TLS 1.1.

The MySQL SSL connector of Google Data Studio only support TLS 1.2 or above.

I upgraded to MariaDB 10.2.x and everything work now.

[For more information](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/115436028/unable-to-connect-to-database-mysql-version-5-6-with-ssl-in-use?msgid=120947817)

Comment: 10.2 uses yassl too, 10.4 was the first version which uses wolfSSL instead of yassl.